# Flutter State not getting updated

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

i am trying to  comment section in social media app in android,the issue is after making the post comment ,the newly added comment is not showing in real time,the state is not getting updated , i tried to check the order of function calls by making print data in  console,
console log

```
I/flutter ( 2069): comment posted succesfully
10
I/flutter ( 2069): getcomments
I/flutter ( 2069): setstate called
```

```
             )),
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async {
                    await CommentService().postComment(
                        commentText: controller.text, postid: widget.postid);
                 await     CommentService().getCommentsdata(post_id: widget.postid);

                    setState(() {
                      controller.clear();
                      print('setstate called');
                   
                   
                    });
                  },
```

Comment: how do you expect to see the result?

Comment: currently i am using a listviewbuilder is using to list all the comments api ,as soon as i post the post the new comment it should be shown as like a  instagram post

Comment: you need to fetch latest data i think you are using future builder so you need to reset the future variable 
by calling 
setstate((){
youfuturevariable=GetService().getlatest();
})
like this

Comment: yeh, mate  i resolved ,i forgot to call the functionality so  that list which stores data will be updated

Comment: @Diljith if please send here code snippet so i posted as answer so this question is close